# Why am I getting an IndexOutOfRangeException in this code?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I basically need to store an array of any amount of contents to an integer but then I have to echo it all out after.

I am getting an indexoutofrange error.

```
for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++, userArray--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + userArray + " Value is:");
            userArrayinputed[userArray] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

All the Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the Size of the Array?");
        string inputArray = Console.ReadLine();
        int userArray = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray);

        int[] userArrayinputed = new int[userArray];

        for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++, userArray--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + userArray + " Value is:");
            userArrayinputed[userArray] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int index = userArray; index > 0; index--, userArray--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userArrayinputed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Correct Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the Size of the Array?");
        string inputArray = Console.ReadLine();
        int userArray = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray);
        int maxArray = userArray;

        int[] userArrayinputed = new int[userArray];

        for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + " Value is:");
            userArrayinputed[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userArrayinputed[index]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the swift responses. I checked the lectures notes and realised I should of used index but thank you guys. It made it a much easier fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index of array is starting from 0 to (userArray -1)

```
    string inputArray = Console.ReadLine();
    int userArray = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray);

    int[] userArrayinputed = new int[userArray];

    for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number " + index+ " Value is:");
        userArrayinputed[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userArrayinputed[index]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the swift resposne

Answer (score 2):

So, array's are zero based for indexing, that means if you want an array of `10` then the indexers are going to be `0-9`.

so when you go up an array (`0-9`) you want the top of a `for` loop to be `<`(less than the array length) when you are going down the array (`9-0`) you want the lower bound to be `>= 0` (less than or equal to the bottom of the array) otherwise you will start out trying to access at `10` (the array length) and get an `OutOfRangeException`.

for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length -1; i++)
{ ... }
```

and

```
for (int i = myArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ ... }
```

and when you are displaying the index in a `for` loop you will want to display the index and not the array length.

Also something of note - you were deducting the value of the `userArray` variable in two separate for loops, which does not reset it when it leaves the loop, so at the end of the method, the `userArray` variable would have been at -(2*userArray) instead of what I think you were going for which was the index/array length.

So it would look something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    Console.WriteLine("What is the Size of the Array?");
    string inputArray = Console.ReadLine();
    int userArray = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray);

    int[] userArrayinputed = new int[userArray];

    for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + " Value is:");
        //note you will get an error here if you try and parse something that isn't an interger
        userArrayinputed[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    for (int index = userArray -1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userArrayinputed[index]);

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
userArrayinputed[userArray]
```

with

```
userArrayinputed[index]
```

and remove the `userArray--` from your `for` loops. Use the index instead to display the current number:

```
for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + " Value is:");
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

Your `for()` loop is first evaluated with userArray == userArrayinputed.Length, so
`userArrayinputed[userArray]` tries to access the (N + 1)th element of the array which leads to the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Array indexing starts with 0, remember? So an array with say, 3 items

```
int[] arr = new int[3]
```

the array has the items `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` but no `arr[3]` which would be the **4th** item.

### Solution

Just use  `userArrayinputed[index]` and remove the `userArray--` part in the `for()` statement.
If you still want to enter the numbers in reverse order you can count down from userArray-1:

```
for (int index = userArray - 1; index >= 0; index--)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + " Value is:");
    userArrayinputed[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

To display the numbers, you should WriteLine the array elements, not the array:

```
for (int index = userArray - 1; index >= 0; index--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(userArrayinputed[index]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, userArrayinputed[userArray] accesses the last index which is userarray-1
since userarray is the length of the array

here is the fix,

```
for (int index = 0; index < userArray; index++, userArray--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + userArray + " Value is:");
                userArrayinputed[userArray-1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
```